# Can't get nested tag in an iframe: receive an empty array "HTMLCollection []"

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a HTML website that inside the iframe I have a `<script>` tag.

I can get the iframe by running:

```html
iframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")
```

When I print `iframe[0]` I received:

```html
<iframe id="576259869" src="https://..." frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen="" class="sc-kVrTmx jfegoL" data-ready="true"></iframe>
#document
 <html lang="en">
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
   <div id="..">...</div>
   <script>...</script>
  </body>
 </html>
</iframe>
```

I tried to catch it like that:

```html
iframe[0].getElementsByTagName("script")
```

But it gives me an empty arrary `HTMLCollection []` although I can see the tag inside the iframe.

Comment: "the tag inside the iframe" – It isn't inside the iframe, it is inside the **document** which is inside the iframe.

Comment: @Quentin so I can I get it ?

Comment: See the duplicates

Comment: @Quentin okay, the second answer might help. When I run `iframe[0].contentWindow.document` it gives me the origin policy error

Comment: The second duplicate covers the cross-origin issue.

Comment: yes, it helps to under. Still weird because I can grab it with the browser GUI, but okay..

Comment: It isn't wird. You, the person who can access the browser GUI, already have permission to access the site displayed in the iframe. Mallory (the hypothetical evil hacker who wrote the webpage you are looking at) **doesn't** have permission to access your online banking service (the hypothetical site displayed in the iframe).

Comment: Yes you are right